# how to create a link field which validates to a set of nodes?

Tags: forms

Is there a way to set the Validation for a Link field so that authors are only allowed to link to a pre-determined certain set of nodes?

IOW: when authors add a link field to a Node I want them to be limited to only links that are on our site -and- which are webforms or other nodes. I do -not- want them to be able to freely link to other domains.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to limit this set of valid links to nodes of a certain content type, or with a certain tag.

Just to be clear: these are not site visitor form fields, these are the fields for -Authors-.

Answer (score 0):

try the [advanced link](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_link) module:

> Provides autocomplete widget for CCK Link field and additional
> functionality over standard field:
>
> Variants of URL filtering (external or internal).
>
> Additional filter options by using URL patterns.
>
> Autocomplete link field for internal mode - displays suggestions from existing url aliases and menu items
>
> Option to allow users select url title from predefined list of values
>
> Use cases
>
> You want allow users specify link only to several sites (i.e. specify link only to facebook or twitter)
>
> **You want restrict users to specify only internal or external links**
>
> You want to use autocomplete suggestion when specifying internal links