# How can I restrict external URLs in link field to allow only certain domains?

Tags: uri, 9

After creating a Link field and use the [Link with service icon](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_icons) format, I find out that there is no option to restrict external URLs to external domains that I want

For example, if I only want to allow Twitter links, something like add `https://www.twitter.com/*`.

[Someone already asked here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129366/how-to-create-a-link-field-which-validates-to-a-set-of-nodes/129377#129377), but it seems that the [Advanced Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_link) module is not available for my Drupal version.

With what module and how can I filter my desired URLs in Drupal 9?

Comment: If you want to add custom validation to entity reference fields you can do that by following this solution.
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294733/adding-constraint-to-entity-referenced-paragraph-field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a now a new module on drupal.org: [Link Allowed Hosts](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_allowed_hosts) – Will be working on this during the week so next week we can finally restrict the allowed hosts for link fields.

Comment: I installed the module and do exactly what I want, including the https option. Thanks for your efforts! The only thing that looks strange is the Link field description (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274143/change-default-help-text-on-link-fields) telling as example link the use of http instead of https but its not related to that module so I will look about change that text. Issue solved :)

Comment: @MrIssue – Oh yeah, I think it is related. I created an issue for it https://www.drupal.org/project/link_allowed_hosts/issues/3200817.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write your own custom validation contraint and add this constraint to your field.

Docs: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint

I've used that example to create a "force HTTPS" link field constraint

`src/Plugin/Validation/Constraint/Https.php`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * Checks that the submitted URL is starting with https://
 *
 * @Constraint(
 *   id = "MY_CONSTRAINT_ID",
 *   label = @Translation("Https", context = "Validation"),
 *   type = "string"
 * )
 */
class Https extends Constraint {
  public $notHttps = '%uri is not a secure site (not starting with https://)';
}
```

`src/Plugin/Validation/Constraint/HttpsValidator.php`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

/**
 * Validates the Https constraint.
 */
class HttpsValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint) {
    $item = $items->first();
    if (!isset($item)) {
      return NULL;
    }

    foreach ($items as $item) {
      /* CHANGE THIS, e.g. here you can check for domain names */
      if (strpos($item->uri, 'https://') !== 0) {
        $this->context->addViolation($constraint->notHttps, ['%uri' => $item->uri]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`MYMODULE.module`

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;

function MYMODULE_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {
  if ($bundle === 'MY_ENTITY_BUNDLE' && $entity_type->id() == 'MY_ENTITY_TYPE') {
    if (isset($fields['MY_FIELD'])) {
      $fields['MY_FIELD']->addConstraint('MY_CONSTRAINT_ID', []);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Uh wow that's nice! Much, much better than hooking into the form!

Comment: Let me ask you Hudri. 1: The Constraint ID is the name I want to choose or there is a list of valid IDs to use? 2: When you say in the 2nd file `here you can check for domain names`, I got to make an array for the domains only, or maintaining the code under that line? If so, where the array for the domains goes exactly? 3: In the 3rd file, `'MY_ENTITY_BUNDLE' what exactly is a bundle? Thanks for your share, I don't have programming skills but it is a short code so maybe I can try with some help. Think that I am only a Site Builder always looking for using core or contributed modules.

Comment: Everything written in uppercase `MY_SOMETHING` is intented to be replaced with custom names/config/module from your own project. But you won't get around coding, at the very least you have to code your own validation logic, which will be quite different than my example (following the lines after ` CHANGE THIS`)

Comment: Can someone explain how to write tests for custom validation like this?

Answer (score 0):

A module exists with that capability, perhaps try https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/wombatbuddy/3183996

Comment: I think that problem needs to get solved on another level since that feature does not only relate to social media providers.